# Radial blend with two different shapes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending-objects

Anyone know how to do this? have tried everything I know of.

Thanks[image]

Comment: I think the key points here are that you need to make the blend between 3 lines. So a blend from line `A` to `B` to `A` and I don't know if there's a better way, but to connect the ends, you may have to add a new anchor point (with pen tool for example) close to the starting point.

Answer (score 7):

I'm assuming you know how to create a blend in Illustrator. If not, see [**here**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html).

- Create the blend vertically.
- Draw a semi-cricle path
- Select the blend and the semi-circle and choose `Object > Blend > Replace Spine`
- At this point it'll look wrong. So choose `Object > Blend > Blend Options`
- Change the **orientation** to "Align to Path" rather than to "Align to Page" (The right option should be depressed, see below)
- adjust the "Specified Steps" as necessary.

[image: blend]

---

The path used for the spine can be any path. The procedure is essentially the same for any blend which does not follow a straight path....

[image]